# why aws deployed app is not pulling the changes on the server from the linked git repository

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-s3, production

I deleted the git branch of the  repository which is linked to website deployed on aws s3. I created the same branch with same name but the server is not pulling changes from git repository.   Please help.

```
    In aws account -
    There are 3 buckets
    1. amplify-admin-dev-deployment ,
    2. amplify-customer-dev-deployment,
    3. media storage

   In media storage bucket, static website hosting is 
   disabled,and
   there is no codepipeline and codebuild created, both are 
   empty.
```

On test server I only see a spinner no page content.

Comment: What is the CI you are using.. CodeBuild or something else? check that first .

Comment: i don't know...how to find that....i have access of aws

Comment: i checked the website hosting is disabled in one of the buckets

Comment: @mongeshmadhavan check  edits

Comment: first 2 buckets might be the hosted version.. check if files still exists inside these two bucket. and try to launch hosted bucket url.

Comment: it has 5 object files but rest of configuration in properties section are empty except tags

Comment: Are those files sufficient to host webiste. If not that means some pipeline wiped off files during your branch delete. 
You can create build from your local and paste those files in bucket for testing. Once proved you can put effort to find Pipeline deployment for this one.

Comment: why aws does not track the changes if anything happened like this, I saw no warning or notification if some files or changes are being made to the configuration

Comment: It depends on policy .. if S3 has version enabled.. you will see history of files deleted etc.

Comment: @mongeshmadhavan how to check what services are we using in aws....because the person who did the aws configuration did'nt told anything if there is any configuration missing....he was also unabled to resolve that

Comment: Billing is simplest way .. as you might not be using cloudformation to track resource.